# Propel schema.xml generation without columns from postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, propel

I am trying to generate a postgres database schema. For example, I made a new table called awesome, with pk and one more column, both varchar(50).

When using postgres reverse, I get this result (missing pk, columns):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database name="default" defaultIdMethod="native" defaultPhpNamingMethod="underscore">
  <table name="awesome" idMethod="native" phpName="Awesome"/>
</database>
```

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database name="default" defaultIdMethod="native" defaultPhpNamingMethod="underscore">
  <table name="awesome" idMethod="native" phpName="Awesome"/>
</database>`